# How to compute gauge potential $A$ from the field strength $F$?

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, yang-mills

Let $F=dA+A \wedge A$ be the field strength that solves vaccum Yang-Mills equation.

The question is: how to recover the gauge potential $A$? Is there any standard way? or any theorem stating the solvability? Suppose the metric is $g=g_{\mu \nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}=\eta_{ab}e^ae^b$, $e^a$ is tetrad basis.

Comment: MathOverflow question about the general mathematical structure behind closed/exact Lie algebra-valued forms: https://mathoverflow.net/q/380237/157071

Answer (score 7):

Even if you only consider the gauge potentials up to gauge equivalence, you *still* can't recover a potential from a field in the non-abelian case. Not even locally! This is called the "field copy problem" in the literature, and goes back to Wu and Yang.

There *are* some special cases where the potential can be recovered from the field, e.g. [if the holonomy group is as big as possible on every open subset](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103909057).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, I think.

Comment: Hi Matt. I agree with this, but there seems to be literature showing otherwise: https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.19.517 does the inversion in the 'completely fixed axial gauge' and https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.26.1368 does it in the 'coordinate gauge' $x^\mu A_\mu=0$.

Answer (score 4):

You can't recover the gauge potential uniquely without specifying more information, because of gauge invariance.  $A$ is not uniquely defined by $F$.  For any gauge transformation $g: \Sigma \to G$, the transformed connection $A^g = g^{-1}A g + g^{-1}dg$ has curvature $F_{A^g} = g^{-1}F_A g$.

It's physically a bit weird to specify $F_A$ in non-Abelian gauge theories.  Gauge transforms don't leave $F_A$ invariant, so $F_A$ isn't an observable.  But if one insists that $F_{A^g} = F_A$, then all connections $A^g$ with $g$ in the centralizer of $F_A$ give the same curvature.

Answer (score 3):

To supplement the answers that were posted earlier, here's an explicit example from ref 1. This example proves that $A$ is not always uniquely determined by $F$, not even up to gauge transformations, not even locally.

Work in four-dimensional spacetime with coordinates $(w,x,y,z)$, and take the structure group to be $SU(2)$. Let $T_1$, $T_2$, $T_3$ be the generators of $SU(2)$, and remember that the only element of $SU(2)$ that commutes with all of the $T_k$ is the identity element. Consider the gauge potential
$$
 A = T_1 w\,dx + T_2 y\,dz + \alpha T_1\,dz
$$
where $\alpha$ is an arbitrary nonzero real number. The field strength is $F=dA+A\wedge A$ with
\begin{align}
 dA 
 &= T_1 dw\wedge dx + T_2 dy\wedge dz
\\
 A\wedge A 
 &= [T_1,T_2]w y\,dx\wedge dz
\\
 &\propto T_3 w y\,dx\wedge dz.
\end{align}
Observe:

- $F$ is independent of $\alpha$, so we have a family of gauge different potentials that all give the same $F$.
- The three two-forms appearing in these expressions for $dA$ and $A\wedge A$ are linearly independent, and their coefficients are the three different generators of $SU(2)$.

Now, consider whether or not these potentials can be gauge-equivalent to each other (equal to each other up to gauge transformations). When we apply a gauge transform $g$ to $A$, its effect on $F$ is $F\to g^{-1} Fg$. But we already know that all of these $A$s give the same $F$, so we must have $g^{-1} F g=F$. Thanks to the observations highlighted above, this implies $g^{-1} T_k g=T_k$ for all $k$, which in turn implies $g=1$. Therefore, the potentials $A$ with different values of the coefficient $\alpha$ cannot be gauge-equivalent to each other, even though they all have the same field strength $F$.

---

**Reference:**

1. Mostow and Shnider (1983), "Counterexamples to Some Results on the Existence of Field Copies" (https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103940415)